# Swap Control and Caps Lock on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, keymap

How can I swap my Control and Caps Lock keys on Windows 7? I've found several options online but all are for previous versions of Windows.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Windows has a built-in feature that lets you flexibly remap keys by adding registry keys corresponding one keycode to another.

This isn't very user-friendly to do manually, so you can get a program called [SharpKeys](http://www.randyrants.com/sharpkeys/) that's a nice GUI to this.

- Just install the program (it's small); start it up.
- Press *Add* below the empty list box.
- You can then choose *Caps Lock* from the left list and *Left Control* or *Right Control* from the right list, or do it the easy way and just click "Type Key" on the left and press your caps lock key and then okay.
- Then do the same thing on the right with either *Left Control* or *Right Control*.
- Then just hit OK, then hit *Write to Registry* in the main window.
- Once this is done you'll need to log off and then back on so that Windows will reload the keyboard settings.

Comment: Looks like it was last updated in 2006, does it work (reliably) on Windows 7?

Comment: Yeah, it still works just fine in Win7 in my experience (although the installer seems to say it's only intended for XP/2003)

Comment: Considering the keyboard driver model hasn't changed considerable in over 20 years...

Comment: Thanks for this answer (and for the question)! I just did it on my Windows 7 Starter Edition netbook and it worked great. I used [SharpKeys 3.0](http://www.randyrants.com/2008/12/sharpkeys_30.html), which was updated in 2008. [There's also source code!](http://sharpkeys.codeplex.com/)