# Remapped keys (with xmodmap) in Linux host stopped working in VirtualBox Windows guest

Tags: linux, windows-8, virtualbox, xmodmap

I've used the following xmodmap script for years to swap my Left Ctrl and Caps Lock keys in Linux:

```
remove Lock = Caps_Lock
remove Control = Control_L
keysym Control_L = Caps_Lock
keysym Caps_Lock = Control_L
add Lock = Caps_Lock
add Control = Control_L
```

It's also worked in my Windows 8 VM, running in VirtualBox, just fine until recently. Now, the remapping no longer applies to the  Windows host - I think it started with the release of VirtualBox 4.3.16. When I try to use the regular Left Ctrl, it triggers Caps Lock in the Linux host.

Comment: It looks like you tried to add a solution to this question to a different answer.  Just post your own solution as an answer (you are allowed to answer your own question).

Comment: Just for reference: there's [one bug report about this](https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/13404).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just install SharpKeys and [follow these directions](https://superuser.com/questions/292724/swap-control-and-caps-lock-on-windows-7/292727#292727) to swap Left Ctrl and Caps Lock. The guest's and host's responses to the two keypresses should then be in sync.